# display of data in meaningful color in Matlab scatter plots

Tags: matlab, colors, plot, data-visualization, scatter

I have about 9000 x,y locations, each with a value, say between -1 and 1. Let's call it a temperature.

I would like to plot each point with red/blue proportional to the point's temperature.

I can scale the values, in RGB, from [0 0 1] to [1 0 0] with G=0, and R+B=1. I want to the coldest points, with temperature -1, to be plotted with [0 0 1], pure blue, a mid-level point might be at [.4 0 .6], and a very hot point would be at [.95 0 .5]

I think there's a way to do this with the scatter command, but I can't figure out how to give a different RGB value to each point. If there's a way to do this with a plot command, I'd be happy to do that instead.

I'd appreciate any guidance you can give me.

Thank you,

Phil

Answer (score 2):

Use the `cdata` property:

```
cdata = [0 0 0;
         1 0 0;
         0 1 0;
         0 0 1;
         1 0 1];
figure;
scatter(1:5, 1:5, 'o','cdata',cdata)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I can make that work. I can calculate the appropriate values for each row of cdata, and then use the scatter command as you showed. Great fast response. I am happy.